# Series of let definitions

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml, let

I'm a beginner in OCaml, and i have a problem with series of let, like:

```
let x = myFun y in
let z = myFun x in
...
```

But, between the lets, i use Hashtbl.iter and other functions that returns unit. If i do:

```
let x = myFun y in
Hashtbl.iter (...) ...
let z = myFun x in
...
```

The compiler raises an error. But, if i do:

```
let x = myFun y in
let h = Hashtbl.iter (...) ...
let z = myFun x in
...
```

The compiler don't raise any error, just warnings showing that "h" is never used. What's the best way to do that without any problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use `;` to separate expressions:

```
e1 ; e2
```

This performs the side-effects in `e1` and discards the result, and then evaluates `e2.

So in your case:

```
let x = myFun y in
Hashtbl.iter (...) ... ;
let z = myFun x in
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that you can write

```
let x = ... in
  let _ = Hashtbl.iter in ...
```